# scraping using proxies in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, proxy

I'm trying a code in which I can scrape using multiple SSL proxies with selenium. Everything works well but I want the code to be able to check if the proxy works or not, if it does it will do a certain task until the proxy gets banned by the website for example, or until it's dead, and jumping to the next proxy if it didn't work.

I have this code below, it does check whether the proxy works, but it just skips to the next proxy even if the previous one works fine. I couldn't figure out why.

Full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
from colorama import Fore, init
import warnings

init(convert=True)
proxy_array = []

with open(r'p.txt') as my_file:
    for list in my_file:
        proxy_array.append(list)

print(Fore.GREEN + 'Fetching proxies...\n')

converted_proxies = []

for element in proxy_array:
    converted_proxies.append(element.strip())

print(Fore.WHITE + 'Proxies are ready for automated testing.\nInitiating...\n')

for prox in converted_proxies:
    PROXY = prox
    webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['acceptSslCerts']=True
    webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['proxy'] = {
        "httpProxy": PROXY,
        "ftpProxy": PROXY,
        "sslProxy": PROXY,
        "proxyType": "MANUAL",

    }

    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    #options.headless = True
    options.add_argument('start-maximized')
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(20)
    index = converted_proxies.index(prox)
    
    try:
        driver.get('https://www.google.com')
        try:
            h1 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('h1')
            if h1.text == u"This site can’t be reached" or h1.text == u"No Internet":
                print(Fore.RED + 'Bad Proxy:', index + 1 ,'/',len(converted_proxies))
                driver.quit()
                break
            else:
                driver.get('http://icanhazip.com/')
                print(driver.page_source)

                print(Fore.GREEN + 'Good Proxy:', index + 1 ,'/',len(converted_proxies))

                driver.quit()
                
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            pass

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        driver.quit()
        pass
    

print(Fore.WHITE + 'Done')
```

Comment: It skips to the next proxies because you're not doing anything inside the else statement to prevent it from continuing through the proxy for a loop. You need another loop somewhere (Either inside the else statement or around try/catch) to keep using the same proxy.

Comment: @ConorReid I do have a code inside the else statement.